# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException : Export property type interface java. util. Map not supported

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have Jasper report to and I want to display that as xls report.

Earlier I had problem of poi libraries for xls writing, solved that problem by adding poi 3.15 libraries with commons-collections4-4. 1.1.

The poi problem was solved, but after these updates the copy of xls report is giving error.

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException : Export property type interface java. util. Map not supported

Answer (score 1):

The exception is caused by a bug in the JasperReports library, see details at https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/10616

Upgrading to JasperReports 6.6.0 or newer should get rid of the problem.